# Storing Gatsby page content

Tags: reactjs, yaml

I'm exploring Gatsby to make a static website with multiple pages. Those pages will have the same template, just the text will change. To make it easier, I'm going to create a single template. I want to store the content of the different pages (text, path etc.)in Yaml or JSON file. So basically it would look like this :

```
import React from "react";
import content from '../content/pageContent.yaml'

const Template = () => {

return (
<header className="div1">
   <div className="flex items-center justify-center container mx-auto">
     <div className="basis-1/2 el tagline">
       <h1>{content.title}</h1>
       <p>{content.description}</p>
       <button>Lets go</button>
     </div>
     <div className="basis-1/2 el">
       <img src=`../images/${pic}`
     </div>
   </div>
 </header>
...
)
}
export template
```

Here is my pageContent.yaml

```
title: YAML content used at build time with Gatsby
description: my description with a <b>bold word</b>
pic: mypicture.png
```

Everything works great but the problem is that it doesn't render the HTML tags. But if I use `<h1 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ {__html: content.titre} }></h1>` instead of  `<h1>{content.title}</h1>` it renders the HTML tag.

My question is : is it ok to make it this way? Would it be a better way to do that ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dangerouslySetInnerHTML` exposes your app to security risks such as Cross-site scripting XSS attacks.

You could use a library like `react-markdown` to convert the markdown to html.

Here is an example of how you could do it, adapt as appropriate.

```
import React from "react";
import content from '../content/pageContent.yaml'
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";

const Template = () => {

return (
<header className="div1">
   <div className="flex items-center justify-center container mx-auto">
     <div className="basis-1/2 el tagline">
       <ReactMarkdown source={content.title} />
       <ReactMarkdown source={content.description} />
       <button>Lets go</button>
     </div>
     <div className="basis-1/2 el">
       <img src=`../images/${pic}`
     </div>
   </div>
 </header>
...
)
}
export template
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't work. With your code nothing appear. I also tried `<ReactMarkdown children={content.description} />` and `<ReactMarkdown> {content.description}<ReactMarkdown />`, title appears but the html tags also, as text

Comment: Ok got it : We need to import rehypeRaw et use it. So first `import rehypeRaw from 'rehype-raw'` and then `<ReactMarkdown rehypePlugins={[rehypeRaw]} children= {content.titre}/>`